# xdebug - remote log time is wrong

Tags: linux, logs, date, php

I noticed that the xdebug log time is always two hours too early. For example it says the log is created at 7:15 am even though it is 9:15 am.

If I execute `date` in my terminal, then I get 9:15 am

Comment: Is this the php xdebug? Is it running with a different time zone, by any chance? What is the full date output?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, no I build it from source, but I also tried it with php7-xdebug and here it is the same. The full output of `date` is currently `Thu Aug  1 15:13:26 CEST 2019`

Comment: Both date outputs...

Comment: The other date is 2 hours too earlie as I said.. so it is 13:13:16

Comment: Is the log in UTC/GMT, though?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, there is no hint about this in the log.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment regarding the current time being `Thu Aug 1 15:13:26 CEST 2019`, my theory is that the xdebug log is running (or logging) in UTC, which is two hours earlier than CEST. It's unfortunate that the timezone doesn't appear to be part of the output; that leaves the actual time ambiguous for any cross-referencing, as you've seen.

I found a [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36129880/4957508) that mentions setting the `date.timezone` value to your desired timezone. It also says:

> It is always better to load xdebug extension at the end of file(php.ini).

The [list of php.ini directives](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) indicates that the default value for `date.timezone` is empty, which presumably falls back to UTC.

My suggestion, since `CEST` is not a valid value, would be to pick your region from [this list of valid PHP European timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php) (or Antarctica or Africa, as appropriate). For more, see the [full list of timezones supported by PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: xdebug was indeed at the start of the php.ini. I placed it at the end and restarted apache2, but it makes no difference. The wrong timezone must be hardcoded in the xdebug module? I have also set `date.timezone` to `Europe/Berlin`, it was `CET`. I talked to the main developer Derik once, he said that xdebug is set to use UTC, but  did not asked if I can change it back then...

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this to work, even with my `date.timezone` set in `php.ini` and `xdebug.ini` loaded afterwards.

My Xdebug log (no longer called "remote log" in Xdebug 3) was still showing `UTC` time. I couldn't find any way to change this other than by editing the Xdebug source and recompiling. I don't see anything in the source code for Xdebug that would convert time to local time, so maybe this is the only way.

See [my stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65526616/631764) to my own question for more details. But here's the gist.

All I had to do was change `gmtime()` to `localtime()` in `src/lib/timing.c` function `char* xdebug_nanotime_to_chars` around line 196.

And that works, but I wanted the timezone code printed in the log.

To do that, I had to make a few more changes. I made a function to return the timezone string, then added that function into the log open/close functions in the same file (`src/lib/log.c`).